# Is it faster to use AutoGenerateColumns or to define my own columns?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with a DataGridView that displays a dataset containing >5,000 rows. I have been trying to make it load faster, and have been able to cut the time from ~12 to ~5.5 seconds so far. The next thing I've considered trying is to define all of the columns instead of using AutoGenerateColumns, but I would like to know if this will help it load any faster before I spend time creating the 20+ columns.

Comment: Sure, it will shave a few milliseconds off, but wont be noticeable. Would suggest looking elsewhere - load less data / paginate, better database indexing, caching, and asynchronous / background prefetching would probably yield better value. /10c

Answer (score 1):

Defining the columns should be marginally faster, but maybe you could benefit more from paging or loading the data on demand.

Take a look: [How to: Implement Virtual Mode with Just-In-Time Data Loading in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/virtual-mode-with-just-in-time-data-loading-in-the-datagrid)